# Incomplete Swagger documentation for SpringBoot endpoint with MultipartFile parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I am using Swagger with SprintBoot to generate the endpoints documentation, it is working great with one exception: I have a POST endpoint with a MultipartFile parameter. In this case Swagger generates the documentation but not the Example Value (it is empty).

```
public String create(@ApiParam(value = "Record to be created", required = true, type = "json", format = "json")
        @RequestPart(name = "candidate") MyDto record,
        @ApiParam(value = "File associated to the record", required = false)
        @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) throws Exception
```

[image]

Without the MultipartFile the Example Value shows the JSON example which can be used. I would like to have the same when an additional (optional) MultipartFile parameter is included.

Can this be addressed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i know swagger docs can be placed when adding annotations something like this:

```
@ApiModel(value="MyFile")
public class MyFile{

  @ApiModelProperty(value = "originalFileName", example="The original filename")
  private String getOriginalFilename;

  [...]
}
```

I would suggest to extend the MultipartFile Object and add this Annotations. So you can add documentation to the params and your optional params too.

P.S. MultipartFile is an Interface so you have to extend one of the Implementations  e.g. CommonsMultipartFile. Than you have to include the org.apache.commons.fileupload dependency to your project (for FileItem).